# python3 - try to get method-variable with function-reference using decorator

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.5 and i try to print the number of function-calls with python-decorator. So here is my example:

```
import inspect
def logWrapper(func):
  def wrapper_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
    wrapper_func.calls += 1
    self.logger.info('Func: {}' .format(func.__name__) )
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  wrapper_func.calls=0

  return wrapper_func


class A:

  __init__(self):
    print('created')

  @logWrapper
  def myfunction1(self, var1):
    print('var1: {}' .format(var1))

  @logWrapper
  def myfunction2(self, var2):
    print('var2: {}' .format(var2))  

if __name__ == "__main__":   
  Pal1=A()
  Pal1.myfunction1('1')
  Pal1.myfunction1('2')
  Pal1.myfunction1('3')
  Pal1.myfunction2('A')

  function_list=inspect.getmembers(Pal1, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
  for func in function_list:
    method_to_call = getattr(A, func[0])
    print( 'Function: {}; Calls: {}' .format(func[0], method_to_call.calls))
```

When i call `Pal1.myfunction1.calls` and `Pal1.myfunction2.calls` i got my correct results 3 and 1. But now i like to iterate throw every function of **class A**. When i try `Pal1.func[0].calls` i got the error-message `*** AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'func'`, i also tried `A.method_to_call.calls` and got the same results.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You are calling instance methods as class methods. Try method_to_call = getattr(Pal1, func[0])

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling instance methods as class methods.

For example, you cannot call

```
A.myfunction1('3')
```

However you can call,

```
inst = A()
inst.myfunction1('3')
```

When this is translated into the `getattr` syntax, your code becomes

```
method_to_call = getattr(Pal1, func[0])
```